# Need help finding source of CSS in Drupal code

Tags: theming, 7

I've added the [share42](https://www.drupal.org/project/share42) module, customized, downloaded it an installed it. It used to work fine. And it still works fine on my local development environment. But its not working on my production environment.

The steps to configure this module, are:

1. install the [share42](https://www.drupal.org/project/share42) module
2. customize the buttons: http://share42.com/
3. download and install the image and js script you created in step 2 in the all/libraries folder
4. put some code in the node.tpl.php file

I did all this, and like I said it looks fine on my development environment. However, when i push it to production it's all messed up and doesn't look right. I cleared caches and ran cron multiple times. I deleted my browser cache. Nothing.

So I did an inspect element on the  that's outputting the share42 buttons on the production server. It's showing some inline styling that I didn't add. So I clicked the linked word 'inline' and it shows me the code for the entire page (just a random node). I don't see the inline styling anywhere on the page referenced in inspect element! It just shows the .js file I'm bringing in via . I've looked at that code though and copied and pasted the contents of my local .js file with the one on the production server and they are identical.

Note: I also deleted and replaced the entire /sites folder on the production server, and the bad styling is still there.

So now I'm a bit exasperated. Not sure what else to try to find out where the incorrect styling is coming from. Anyone have any other suggestions for places to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a file permission problem on your production server for the library you added to your all/libraries folder. I.e. that some read access to those files in that folder is not granted.

Another reason MIGHT be that your library folder name (within all/libraries) is NOT named `share42` (case sensitive, so Share42 would NOT be ok). Variation of that could be that "share42.js" and/or "icons.png" cannot be found in that folder (eg beause it got renamed to something else).

Comment: thanks. I'm not sure I understand. I right-clicked the folder for share42 and it shows owner permissions as read/write/execute all checked. Everyone has read permissions. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @Sage Merci (oeps: thank you) for the accept! A bit late (I had forgotten about it), but better late then never, right?

Comment: Yes, my apologies for the late accept!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CSS aggregation enabled? Your note on deleting the /sites folder on production tells me that it could be an issue with the permissions for your directory where the CSS files are all aggregated.

For me, it's sites/*/css. The web server needs write permissions to that folder in order for it to aggregate the CSS and write it there. It could be that you're not seeing the right CSS because it can't write to the directory.

Check the permissions. A quick way to test this is to turn off CSS aggregation on your site and flush the CSS cache. That won't be good for performance, so I wouldn't recommend it for a huge site.

Comment: thanks. I do have css agg enabled. So i disabled that (and javascript) and turned off caching, saved it, and then re-cleared the cache. Still the sharebar is showing up in the wrong spot with that CSS I don't know where its coming from. I checked the permissions of the share42 directory in /libraries and it  says all have permission to read and owner can write and execute.

Comment: Hmm...Well if you disabled aggregation and cleared your cache, then I don't think my answer is correct. What OS are you running?

Comment: my server is on Linux.

Comment: By /libraries, do you mean /sites/all/libraries?

Comment: Also, you'll need to make sure that the /sites folder and its subdirectories have the correct permissions, which means you should also make sure that the owner and group are properly set so that your web server can do what it needs to. Since you deleted the /sites folder, the ownership may have changed when you recreated it. This is a good reference: https://www.drupal.org/node/244924

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: I deleted the entire sites folder BECAUSE this was happening so it's not because I recreated the sites folder. I can do anything else I want with any of the other files/directories on the site.

Comment: @Sage So switching to a default Drupal theme, like Bartik, does not fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm stumped. My only other thought at this point without looking at code is your settings.php file. The project page says you might have to make changes to it if you're running a multi-site.